# OAuth2 using Qt - how to cath redirect_uri using Qt

Tags: qt, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am writing an OAuth2 client using Qt. For the first stage of authorization, I use qml WebView: a link opens in it, where the user enters data and confirms his actions, after which the google service calls `redirect_uri` (there is a user scheme like `"com.mycompany.myappname://"`, which I give google when registering an OAuth2 client). Google specifies the result in the parameters in this redirect and sends the authorization code (it looks something like this: `"com.mycompany.myappname://?code=4/ABCDEFG&scope=email openid&authuser=1&prompt=consent"`, where the `"code"` parameter is used for the following authorization stage - obtaining an `access_token`). Now, to catch this redirect, I use the Java Activity to which my scheme is attached. Activity reads parameters and sends them to C++ using `public static native` method. Next, in C++, the second stage of OAuth2 authorization passes.

**Question**: Is it possible to catch `redirect_uri` using Qt methods? In order to completely abandon Java and thereby make this client cross-platform for Android and IOS (in IOS, if I'm not mistaken, `redirect_uri` is also used with the result of the first stage of OAuth2 authorization).

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I don't think Qt provide a cross platform solution to accomplish your goal. A cross platform solution may be to use an intermediate server, i.e. set the `redirect_uri` to your server and let your app fetch the result from your server.

Comment: Okay thanks! It turns out that you can achieve my goal either in your own way, or by prescribing a redirect mechanism for each platform separately.
Thanks again for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler` something like in this [official example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtnetworkauth.git/tree/examples/oauth/twittertimeline/twitter.cpp?h=5.15).

Then the `redirect_url` might be `127.0.0.1` and then you can handle the payload/url parameters from an [appropriate signa](https://QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler::callbackReceived)l from [QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractoauthreplyhandler.html).